# Socket Programming PHP script keeps loading

Tags: php, sockets

I want to implement a chat application in which php will act as a server and android will act as a client.

The problem is that php script keeps on loading and doesn't stop.When I introduce a loop to listen and output messages continously sent from my android emulator.But when I remove the loop it keeps on loading and as soon as I send message from my android emulator it outputs it once and the script stops.Now I don't know how to accomplish this(i.e whenever I send messages from android it echo's them on the page and keeps on doing it until i send an exit message which exits the script).

Here's my php script:

```
 set_time_limit (0);

$address = '10.116.27.107';
$port = 1234;

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');

socket_listen($sock);
while(1)
{
   $client = socket_accept($sock);
   $input = socket_read($client, 1024);

   $output = preg_replace("[ \t\n\r]","",$input).chr(0);
   socket_write($client, $output);

       if($input=="exit")
   break;

echo $input;

socket_close($client);

}
socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't stop loading"? Are you trying to open it in a browser? Actually, server part *is meant* to never stop loading, until it is forced to quit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to implement a chat app you'll have to improve your code so that it can handle *multiple connections*, which is quite a bit more complicated than just reading and writing to one client. From my experience it is a huge leap from a singular user system to a multi-user, which is why it takes time to learn how to write a chat system by trial and error.

However I believe doing the above would help you avoid your problems, which I would guess are most probably due to what is called **blocking** - the system is waiting for input/output before it continues on and isn't getting any.

Basically there are a few things you need to take in to account with chat apps:

1. You need to be running your chat script from php command line, running in-browser will present you with more complicated problems with regards to timeouts and exactly how a browser expects a web page to work. If you use Mac OSX you can use terminal, if you know linux you can obviously use linux, if you are on Windows... get puTTY and connect to a linux server, I'm sure you can run php command line on Windows, it just not something I've ever tried (*or wished*) to do.
2. You'll need to use `socket_select()` there are some simple examples of how to use this here in the user comments, http://uk.php.net/socket_select.
3. You always need to be aware what state a client is in - i.e. only read when you can read, only write when you can write... and usually if you can either read or write then you **must** do so in order for things to keep working smoothly (and not end up freezing) - chat applications are quite tricky precisely for this reason.
4. Clients can suddenly disconnect and connect, so you need to handle this in amongst the read and writing process.
5. Whenever reading and writing - especially using php - the read and write functions may not send or receive all their information in one go. Similar to `fwrite()` and `fread()` you should check to see how much has been written (and continue to write if not completed) and continue to read until nothing else is left to be read.
6. Depending on your clients certain systems expect messages to end / terminate with specific termination chracters - i.e \n or \0. Most chat applications either detect which to use or send both as part of every discreet message.